# How to flash Huawei P30 firmware via PC?

Tags: rom-flashing, huawei, android-10

I need info on how to flash Huawei P30 rom without sd card via PC.

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried to use dload method but this phone doesn't take an sd card
I've tried using SigmaKey but that fails on my PC
I've tried fastboot but the images on the unpacked firmware are not the same as on the tutorials I even tried to download a different version but still the images  (boot.img, recovery.img etc ) are missing
I've tried a lot I even posted about it in a different question but got no response